# Fastest way to query huge list in mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb, performance, search, pymongo

I want to get details of large set of users from mongodb.
The user list is of more than 100 thousands.
As mongodb dose not support very huge data query in one go.
I want to know which is the best way to get the data.

1. Divide list in groups and get data

> *groups_of_list contains list of userId with bunches of 10000*
>
> ```
> for group in groups_of_list:
>     curr_data = db.collection.find({'userId': {'$in': group}})
>     data.append(curr_data)
> ```

2. Loop over collection

> ```
> for doc in db.collection.find({}):
>    if i['userId'] in set_of_userIds:
>        data.append(doc)
> ```

I want to get the fasted method.

If there is any better method/way, please point it out.

Comment: Could you add some details on the structure of the db.collection? That would make it much easier to help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMHO you should probably separate into "reasonable sized" chunks as in the method 1 you pointed out, not so much for Mongo's limitations, but for your own machine's memory limitations.

It should probably be something like this:

```
def get_user_slice_data(groups_of_list):
    for group in groups_of_list:
        yield list(db.collection.find({'userId': {'$in': group}}))
```

This generator function can be used like this:

```
for use_slice_data in get_user_slice_data(groups_of_list):
    # do stuff
```

By doing this, you will be both avoiding having a big amount of data in memory, and reducing the size of the Mongo transaction as well.

pd: you should probably consider adding an index on 'userId' first, like:

```
db.collection.ensure_index('userId')
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use cursors with fixed limit and iterate over the results using the cursor. You can find more info here - https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/tutorial/iterate-a-cursor/

But actual code implementation depends on the language you are using. If it's Spring, Java application for example you can use Pageable request, something like

```
Pageable pageable = new PageRequest(0, 50);
Query query = new Query();
query.with(pageable);

mongoTemplate.find(query, User.class);

//get the next page 
pageable = pageable.next();
```

Though, do keep in mind that if you are updating your data as you are iterating over it, it could give inconsistent results. So, in that case you have to do a query using snapshot. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.snapshot/

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks Puran that helped.

Comment: You should accept the answer if you think it helped :)